# Is there a way to search for old tweets on a specific date using a specific hashtag?

Tags: twitter

For example how could search for tweets using the #oldtweets sent on 5-29-16, from 8pm to 9pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the The Twitter Search API documentation, the query you want is not possible: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets
>   published in the past 7 days.

Beyond the last 7 days, what you want to achieve can only be done through manually searching an account on Twitter.

Another alternative would be to use https://webrecorder.io/

Scroll to the timeframe you want to record or you can attempt to capture the entire feed. Note the auto scrolling option as well.